# Application onCreate called(not called) after Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android

In crash logs, I've found very strange application bug which happens on android 7.0-8.0 for some small amount of users, but quite frequently. I was not able to reproduce the issue, here the code which reflects the current application status.

I have a static reference to my application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private static MyApplication sInstance;

   public static MyApplication get() {
      return sInstance;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      sInstance = this;
   }
}
```

In the main activity I do initialization of a singleton:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initSingletone();
        super.onCreate(createBundleNoFragmentRestore(savedInstanceState))
    }

    public void initSingleTone(){
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance(); 
    }
}
```

The singleton:

```
public class Singleton{

    public static Singleton instance;
    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return ;
    }

    public Singleton(){
        Context context = MyApplication.get();
        final File baseDir = context.getCacheDir();
        ....
    }
}
```

The `NullPointerException` occurs on the following line.

```
final File baseDir = context.getCacheDir();
```

Because for some reasons `MyApplication.get()` returns null. 
Seems `onCreate` of the `Application` was not called in the moment of `onCreate` of `MainActivity`, really weird.
Have anyone faced with the same problem? 
What could be a reason for such strange initialization process of the Android components?

Comment: Where is `sInstance` declared ?

Comment: @VikashBijarniya updated the code

Comment: share your manifest also

Comment: @sohaibkarim please read the description, I was not able to reproduce the issue on my side, so for the app is working fine. It means that in the application manifest MyApplication is defined.

Comment: Have you added application name as MyApplication in your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Have you tried getting your application from activity? Would that work for you?

Comment: @Aaron, thanks, currently I think in this direction and will try to implement some custom solution, which will provide context to the singleton instances in the app.

Comment: Understood. Your code looks alright, but do you have `android:process` declared on any of your activities in your manifest?

Comment: @Aaron Not it is not declared. It is a really difficult riddle.

Answer (score 0):

Move `sInstance = this;` to constructor.

onCreate() is too late.

In my opinion, this is an Android bug. There is no obvious reason to do anything with the activity if onCreate() of the application has not finished executing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a safe method:

```
public static MyApplication get() {
if(sInstance == null){
 sInstance = this;
 }
    return sInstance;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that it safe, because if onCreate in Application was not called it possible could mean that application context was not initialized yet and I could receive an error during trying to access to any resources.

Comment: This is not normally seen but if it's happening then we need logs of the crash. And it is never possible to access resources while your application class is not initialized.

Comment: i think you should try disabling instant run, then clean the project and re build.   Instant Run has multiple weird issues.

Comment: if getResource on application instance will be called before super.attachBaseContext of the instance was executed, the app will crash with NullPointerExeption.

Comment: @VikashBijarniya you cant return `this` in `static` methods. There is no `this` there. `Static` methods share between all objects of class.