# Android Application onCreate is not called before Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, crash, oncreate

On Google Play I receive a `NullPointerException` when trying to access a static `Application` instance. It appears on different Android OS versions: Android 9, 8, and 6.

From code it seems that `Application.onCreate()` hasn't been called or is called after `Activity.onCreate()`.

I saw similar questions but without any useful response:

[Application onCreate called(not called) after Activity onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607129/application-oncreate-callednot-called-after-activity-oncreate)

[Android Activity::onCreate called before Application.onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795368/android-activityoncreate-called-before-application-oncreate)

As a side solution, I'm going to create a separate singleton class depending on `Context` and get it with the `Context`. But, I'm not sure how it will work with Dagger.

My questions are:

1. Is it an Android bug?
2. Am I doing something wrong?
3. How have other developers solved it?

```
public class App extends androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ComponentCallbacks2 {
    private static App instance;

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;

        // init singletone
    }

    private Singletone singletone;

    public Singletone getSingletone() {}
}

public class MainActivity extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // On Google Play it produces NullPointerException

        Singletone singletone = App.getInstance().getSingletone();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name">
    <application
        android:name=".app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Launcher"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your MainActivity without launcher intent filter or you didn't write it here?

Comment: Show the _"// init singletone"_ code.

Comment: @H.Taras, MainAcitity contains launcher intent filter. You're right, I just did not post it here.

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: @Onik , there just something like new Singleton(Context context).

And in Singleton constructor, I just get application context from context. And init Mixpanel analytics from it. That's it

Comment: I have the same problem. I realized that the application is not yet fulled initialized when the activity starts. I have a static settings member in my apllication. It's filled in onCreate(). I'm pretty shure it worked many years. Maybe it's a problem with AndroidX...

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `instance = this;` from onCreate() to App's constructor.